# Strange Application of the Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

A CEO of a distribution company has gone mad. He chooses the distribution centers that trucks go to by flipping a coin, with probability $p$ for heads and $1-p$ for tails. He oversees $n$ distribution centers and selects pairs from that list. If the coin lands heads, he runs a truck from Center A to B, if tails, he does not. He is curious as to the number of trucker triangles that will form; that is, when three given distribution centers mutually send trucks to each other, such as when A goes to B and B goes to A, B goes to C and C goes to B, and A goes to C and C goes to A. What is the expected number of triangles?

This problem was a bit tricky, but I've made some progress.

I know that the expected number of runs that a given center will have. This sort of problem clearly fits the binomial, so
$$X\sim B(n,p) \, , \, E[X] = np $$
However, a distribution center can't match up with itself, so we adjust this by changing $n$ to $n-1$.
So
$$X\sim B(n-1,p)\, , \, E[X] = (n-1)p$$

Now, to form a mutual triangle, we'd need to have the three vertex distribution centers send out trucks to the other vertices, and vice versa, so I was thinking that examining the probability that a given center has more than one run.

$$ P(X>1) = 1-P(X\leq1) = 1 - \dbinom{n-1}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-1} - \dbinom{n-1}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-2}  $$

I'm thinking now that I'd go about defining a $rv$ for these trucker triangles, but I'm not entirely sure how to encompass all the possibilities. My first guess was to define it as a binomial, with $ n=E[X]$ from before and $p = 1 - \dbinom{n-1}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-1} - \dbinom{n-1}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-2}$, but just because a given center has two connections surely doesn't imply that it connects to its vertices (although if there are only 3 distribution centers, it does). However, even if this was satisfied and we were dealing with $n=3$ distribution centers, we would need to somehow guarantee that the other vertices behaved the same way.

Another approach I had in mind...If we had three distribution centers $A, B, C$ and the events $I, J, K$ corresponded to the scenario where each center sent runs to the other two, then the event where the triangle would be formed would $I\cap J\cap K$, and as these are independent, it would just be the products of their probabilities. However, I don't know how I would go about generalizing this approach to $n$ distribution centers.

Would appreciate any help or thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $t=\binom{n}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ distribution centres.

For $i=1$ to $t$, define random variable $X_i$ to be $1$ if the set of three distribution centres indexed by $i$ mutually send trucks to each other, and $X_i$ to be $0$ otherwise.

Then the number $W$ of "triangles" is $X_1+\cdots+X_t$. By the linearity of expectation and symmetry, we have $E(W)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_t)=tE(X_1)$.

One can see that $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)=p^6$, so $E(W)=\binom{n}{3}p^6$.

**Remark:** The method of indicator random variables gives a way of computing the expectation of a random variable $W$ while bypassing the sometimes very difficult problem of finding the distribution of $W$. Note that the $X_i$ here are not independent. But linearity of expectation holds for all sums of random variables, independent of not.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but I'll have to chew on it a little bit to fully understand it. I greatly appreciate your help though. Were my earlier thoughts about expectation and probability correct though? What do you think?

Comment: The number of trucks sent from any distribution centre indeed has binomial distribution, parameters $n-1$ and $p$. For triangles there is not much progress, since any pair A, B can take part in several triangles. By the way, a possibly more interesting definition of triangle would be A sends to B which sends to C which sends to A, instead of the "two-way" triangles of your definition.

Comment: Hahaha, yes, I do believe a circular triangle would be quite interesting to study!